# Python import error: Cannot improt blend_modes from blend_modes

Tags: python, image, image-processing

I am trying to use blend modes module and examples from this link https://pythonhosted.org/blend_modes/ . I installed blend modes using pip (given in the page) and I still get this error. Any idea how to address this?

Line where the error occurs:

```
from blend_modes import blend_modes
```

Error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'blend_modes' from 'blend_modes' (C:\Users\user1\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\blend_modes\__init__.py)
```

Thanks.

Comment: It looks like `blend_modes` does not exist inside the `blend_modes` module. You could import the module `import blend_modes`, and then use one of its functions such as `soft_light`, `lighten_only`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation you've pointed seems to be bugged. Better to read the one available in GitHub (https://github.com/flrs/blend_modes/#usage) or at https://blend-modes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/.

You will found as an examples of library import:

```
from blend_modes import soft_light
```